# How to pass an array into html table last row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a page that has function on click to make a new `column` in the last column of my table.

The code works but it makes a `column` as much as the array that I have. 
I just want make one `column` in my last table `column`.

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#display_data').on("click", function(e) {
    var myTableArray = [];
    $(".table-bordered tr").each(function() {
      var tdValue = ($(this).find("td:eq(4)").text());
      var a = 1.000;
      var b = 10.000;
      var c = 20.000;
      var d = 45.000;

      var callback1 = '10.000';
      var callback2 = '20.000';
      var callback3 = '37.500';
      var callback4 = '45.000';
      if (tdValue > a && tdValue < b) {
        $('.table-bordered').find('tr').each(function() {
          $(this).find('td').eq(5).after('<td>' + callback1 + '</td>');
        });
      } else if (tdValue > b && tdValue <= c) {
        $('.table-bordered').find('tr').each(function() {
          $(this).find('td').eq(5).after('<td>' + callback2 + '</td>');
        });
      } else if (tdValue > c && tdValue <= d) {
        $('.table-bordered').find('tr').each(function() {
          $(this).find('td').eq(5).after('<td>' + callback3 + '</td>');
        });
      } else {
        $('.table-bordered').find('tr').each(function() {
          $(this).find('td').eq(5).after('<td>' + callback4 + '</td>');
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>WCB</td>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>5006538574</td>
      <td>10.08.2017</td>
      <td>30.830</td>
      <td>KG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>WCB</td>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>5006539622</td>
      <td>10.08.2017</td>
      <td>21.080</td>
      <td>KG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>WCB</td>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>5006539759</td>
      <td>10.08.2017</td>
      <td>40.990</td>
      <td>KG</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="submit" id="display_data" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
```

You can look at my snippet the `column` that has made. That `column` was not that i want.

I want the `column` to be like this:

1. WCB | 101 | 5006538574 | 10.08.2017 | 30.830 | KG | 37.500
2. WCB | 101 | 5006538574 | 10.08.2017 | 30.830 | KG | 37.500
3. WCB | 101 | 5006538574 | 10.08.2017 | 30.830 | KG | 37.500

I hope someone can help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already iterating over all `<tr>` elements in the outer loop, there's no need to do that again in conditional expressions. Instead, you should use currently iterated element (`$(this)`):

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#display_data').on("click", function(e) {
    var myTableArray = [];
    $(".table-bordered tr").each(function() {
      var tdValue = ($(this).find("td:eq(4)").text());
      var a = 1.000;
      var b = 10.000;
      var c = 20.000;
      var d = 45.000;

      var callback1 = '10.000';
      var callback2 = '20.000';
      var callback3 = '37.500';
      var callback4 = '45.000';
      if (tdValue > a && tdValue < b) {
        $(this).find('td').eq(5).after('<td>' + callback1 + '</td>');
      } else if (tdValue > b && tdValue <= c) {
        $(this).find('td').eq(5).after('<td>' + callback2 + '</td>');
      } else if (tdValue > c && tdValue <= d) {
        $(this).find('td').eq(5).after('<td>' + callback3 + '</td>');
      } else {
        $(this).find('td').eq(5).after('<td>' + callback4 + '</td>');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>WCB</td>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>5006538574</td>
      <td>10.08.2017</td>
      <td>30.830</td>
      <td>KG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>WCB</td>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>5006539622</td>
      <td>10.08.2017</td>
      <td>21.080</td>
      <td>KG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>WCB</td>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>5006539759</td>
      <td>10.08.2017</td>
      <td>40.990</td>
      <td>KG</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="submit" id="display_data" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
```

Comment: OMG..
it just because im checking the `tr` again or i can say it `iterated the element of tr` it make the data output has been duplicating?